# How to create mysite.wsgi file?

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I am following this tutorial http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html to setup django with nginx and uwsgi. But I am confused about this line:

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --module mysite.wsgi
```

In the tutorial there's nothing about mysite.wsgi file. What should be the content of this file?

Comment: This is created for you by `django-admin.py startproject`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually, that's not a filename.

That's a python module path.

The relevant file is actually `mysite/wsgi.py` (but to import it in a python interpreter, you'd have to `import mysite.wsgi`, hence the name used in command line).